# How to calculate String values in this case?

Tags: java, string, types, integer

Here are two `String` values for calculating. At the end i need one double value

```
int weight_int = Integer.valueOf("65");
int height_int = Integer.valueOf("185");
double imt =((weight_int/(height_int*height_int))*10000);
```

Comment: What’s the issue? Integer division? (That’s a hint.)

Comment: Your question is poorly worded and is therefore getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Double, you can't get it by dividing two Integers.  You need to cast one of them to a Double.